# how can i get single value from recylerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i have passed data from recyclerview adapter to main activity and then into other activity on click on image of recyclerview.
now i am getting multiple value from it and i just want single URL
here is the code of adapter

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Datum datum = datums.get(position);

        Glide.with(context).load(datums.get(position).getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        holder.title.setText(datum.getTitle());
        holder.artist.setText(datum.getArtist());
        holder.duration.setText(Integer.toString(datum.getDuration()));

        //imageview interface pass
        holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onImageClickListener.onImageClick(datum.getUrl());
                onImageClickListener.onImageClick(datum.getThumbnail());
            }
        });
    }
```

onclick event in main recylerview main activity

```
 public void onImageClick(String imageData ) {

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,exoplayer.class);
        i.putExtra("image", imageData);
        i.putExtra("url", imageData);
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

and here is the code of other activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exoplayer);

        thumb = findViewById(R.id.thumb);
        link = findViewById(R.id.link);

        String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");


        link.setText(url);
        Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(image).into(thumb);

    }
```

here are the screenshots of output

[image: first output]

[image]

i just want that bigger url i do not need other url which url of thumbnail.

Comment: I don't understand what is it that you want, the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Okay from what I tried to understand, is that the `url` is passed twice and you want it to be passed once:

Well if that is the case:

**Update the method in the `onImageClickListener` interface:**

```
 //make the method accept two parameters

 public void onImageClick(String imageData , String urlData);
```

**Next update the method implemented in `MainActivity`:**

```
 public void onImageClick(String imageData , String urlData) {

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,exoplayer.class);
        i.putExtra("image", imageData);
        i.putExtra("url", urlData);
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

**Finally when you click in the `RecyclerView` item, do this:**

```
    //imageview interface pass
    holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onImageClickListener.onImageClick(datum.getThumbnail() , datum.getUrl());
        }
    });
```